# How to warp an image using deformed mesh

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to generate "crumpled" images using images obtained from a  flatbed bed scanner.

By following the method described in the paper[[Link]](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Ma_DocUNet_Document_Image_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf) in the section 3.1. I've written the code generate the perturbed mesh but I don't know how to map this pixels from source image onto this mesh to form the perturbed image.

This is the code to generate the perturbed mesh.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mr = 88
mc = 68

xx = np.arange(mr-1, -1, -1)
yy = np.arange(0, mc, 1)
[Y, X] = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
ms = np.transpose(np.asarray([X.flatten('F'), Y.flatten('F')]), (1,0))

perturbed_mesh = ms
nv = np.random.randint(20) - 1
for k in range(nv):
    #Choosing one vertex randomly
    vidx = np.random.randint(np.shape(ms)[0])
    vtex = ms[vidx, :]
    #Vector between all vertices and the selected one
    xv  = perturbed_mesh - vtex
    #Random movement 
    mv = (np.random.rand(1,2) - 0.5)*20
    hxv = np.zeros((np.shape(xv)[0], np.shape(xv)[1] +1) )
    hxv[:, :-1] = xv
    hmv = np.tile(np.append(mv, 0), (np.shape(xv)[0],1))
    d = np.cross(hxv, hmv)
    d = np.absolute(d[:, 2])
    d = d / (np.linalg.norm(mv, ord=2))
    wt = d
    
    curve_type = np.random.rand(1)
    if curve_type > 0.3:
        alpha = np.random.rand(1) * 50 + 50
        wt = alpha / (wt + alpha)
    else:
        alpha = np.random.rand(1) + 1
        wt = 1 - (wt / 100 )**alpha
    msmv = mv * np.expand_dims(wt, axis=1)
    perturbed_mesh = perturbed_mesh + msmv

plt.scatter(perturbed_mesh[:, 0], perturbed_mesh[:, 1], c=np.arange(0, mr*mc))
plt.show()
```

This is how the perturbed mesh looks like:
[image]

This is the screenshot from the paper illustrating the synthetic image generation:[image]

Sample source image for testing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/26KN4.jpg

I'm stuck with mapping the source image pixels onto the mesh. I'll be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 5):

(1) Use `cv2.copyMakeBorder` to enlarge the image, to avoid the warpped points going out of range of the original image size.

```
cv2.copyMakeBorder(...)
    copyMakeBorder(src, top, bottom, left, right, borderType[, dst[, value]]) -> dst
    .   @brief Forms a border around an image.
    .
    .   The function copies the source image into the middle of the destination image. The areas to the
    .   left, to the right, above and below the copied source image will be filled with extrapolated
    .   pixels. This is not what filtering functions based on it do (they extrapolate pixels on-fly), but
    .   what other more complex functions, including your own, may do to simplify image boundary handling.
```

useage:

```
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, dh, dh, dw, dw, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0))
```

Set `dw=nw//2, dh=nh//2` maybe ok, adjust if necessary. The `nh, nw` is the height and width of the source image.

(2) Create perturbed mesh grid using [the method from the paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Ma_DocUNet_Document_Image_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf)

```
xs, ys = create_grid() # the result is like np.meshgrid
```

Notice make sure the type and the size.

```
# xs = xs.reshape(nh, nw).astype(np.float32)
# nh, nw is the height and width of the coppied image
```

(3) Use `cv2.remap` to remap:

```
cv2.remap(...)
    remap(src, map1, map2, interpolation[, dst[, borderMode[, borderValue]]]) -> dst
    .   @brief Applies a generic geometrical transformation to an image.
    .
    .   The function remap transforms the source image using the specified map:
    .   \f[\texttt{dst} (x,y) =  \texttt{src} (map_x(x,y),map_y(x,y))\f]
```

usage:

```
dst= cv2.remap(img, xs, ys, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

This is a demo result:

[image]

(4) Crop the nonzero region and resize if necessary:

[image]

---

Related:

1. [Converting opencv remap code from c++ to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460962/converting-opencv-remap-code-from-c-to-python/52462982#52462982)
2. [Split text lines in scanned document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981144/split-text-lines-in-scanned-document/48268334#48268334)

Comment: how did you resize the grid ? I'm getting an assertion error when I use `cv2.remap` with full image size grid. `cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1728: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.cols < 32767 && dst.rows < 32767 && src.cols < 32767 && src.rows < 32767 in function 'remap'`

Comment: I think its better if `cv2.copyMakeBorder` is used after `cv2.remap`

Comment: `cv2.remap` generate the result with the same size of the `src`. Use `cv2.copyMakeBorder` first to create a larger `src` with border, so we can the full wrapped `src`. Otherwise, it's of no use. Then to be honest, my `xs, ys` format is `(nheight, nwidth)`, see the link of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460962/converting-opencv-remap-code-from-c-to-python/52462982#52462982).

Comment: What is the version of your opencv ?

Comment: I'm getting this `cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1728: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.cols < 32767 && dst.rows < 32767 && src.cols < 32767 && src.rows < 32767 in function 'remap'`. When I googled I found its due to large number of elements in `perturbed_mesh`. I've been trying to fix this. Did you create meshgrid with original size of the image ? Did you use my code  ?

Comment: Yeah I've read your comments and I have used `cv2.copyMakeBorder` before `cv2.remap` and I have also changed my `xs, ys` format to `(nheight, nwidth)`. It still throws an error. https://github.com/fengju514/Face-Pose-Net/issues/23 check this issue.

Comment: I write the pertubed_mesh by myself. And before `cv2.remap`, I  did this op: `xs = xs.reshape(nh, nw).astype(np.float32)`. Notice, `nh, nw` is the height and width of 
 the coppied image.

Comment: One last question how did you handle mesh points going out of range of image size.  That is, after perturbing the mesh some points are going out of the range of (nh, nw).

Comment: The first step `cv2.copyMakeBorder` do the job. I use `dw=nw//2, dh=nh//2`, almost ok. You can use bigger dw and dw if it's necessary.

Comment: @Kinght金 can you please post the code to generate the mesh (`create_grid`)? The code posted above by OP is wrong.

Comment: Hi could you please provide the code of `create_grid`? thanks!

Comment: @Kinght金 Can you please share full code here?

Mesh perturbation and warping using the source image you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving a minimum working demo for other readers.

Currently, trying to figure out in which condition `perturbed_mesh` becomes `None`.

```py
def deform(img, perturbed_mesh):
    h,w = img.shape[:2]

    perturbed_mesh_x = perturbed_mesh[:,0]
    perturbed_mesh_y = perturbed_mesh[:,1]
    
    perturbed_mesh_x =perturbed_mesh_x.reshape((h,w))
    perturbed_mesh_y =perturbed_mesh_y.reshape((h,w))

    remapped = cv2.remap(img, perturbed_mesh_x, perturbed_mesh_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR) 

    return remapped

def get_perturbed_mesh(img):
    """
        Author: papabiceps
        https://stackoverflow.com/q/53907633
    """

    # mesh row & col
    mr,mc = img.shape[:2]

    xx = np.arange(0, mr, 1)
    yy = np.arange(mc-1, -1, -1)

    # yy = np.arange(0, mc, 1)
    [Y, X] = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

    ms = np.transpose(np.asarray([X.flatten('F'), Y.flatten('F')]), (1,0))
 
    perturbed_mesh = ms
    nv = np.random.randint(20) - 1

    for k in range(nv):
        #Choosing one vertex randomly
        vidx = np.random.randint(np.shape(ms)[0])
        vtex = ms[vidx, :]
        #Vector between all vertices and the selected one
        xv  = perturbed_mesh - vtex
        #Random movement 
        mv = (np.random.rand(1,2) - 0.5)*20
        hxv = np.zeros((np.shape(xv)[0], np.shape(xv)[1] +1) )
        hxv[:, :-1] = xv
        hmv = np.tile(np.append(mv, 0), (np.shape(xv)[0],1))
        d = np.cross(hxv, hmv)
        d = np.absolute(d[:, 2])
        d = d / (np.linalg.norm(mv, ord=2))
        wt = d
        
        curve_type = np.random.rand(1)
        if curve_type > 0.3:
            alpha = np.random.rand(1) * 50 + 50
            wt = alpha / (wt + alpha)
        else:
            alpha = np.random.rand(1) + 1
            wt = 1 - (wt / 100 )**alpha
        msmv = mv * np.expand_dims(wt, axis=1)

        perturbed_mesh = perturbed_mesh + msmv

        perturbed_mesh = perturbed_mesh.astype(np.float32)

        if perturbed_mesh is not None:
            result = deform(img, perturbed_mesh)

            flipped = cv2.flip(result,1)

            cv2.imshow("before",result)
            cv2.imshow("after",flipped)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
 

def main():
    img = cv2.imread("./sample.png")

    get_perturbed_mesh(img)
```

Comment: In `mv = (np.random.rand(1,2) - 0.5)*20`, `20` determines the intensity of deformation!