# How to warp a document image using a deformed mesh (invertible)

Tags: python, opencv, image-manipulation

I want to warp a document image on a deformed mesh as follows:

[image]

A semi-correct approach is described here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907633/how-to-warp-an-image-using-deformed-mesh)

However, i am in particular interested in an **invertible** mapping, ideally, a one way operation (without having to pad the image, as it would be the case when using cv2.remap).

Example procedure:

**Step 1:** Obtain deformed mesh (for a given image src)

```
 xx_deformed = xx + vx
 yy_deformed = yy + vy
```

where vx and vy describes the deformation (see link above).

**Step 2:** Map image on mesh:

```
 warped_img = one_way_operation(src, xx_deformed, yy_deformed)
```

**Step 3:**
undo deformation:

```
 xx_inv = xx - vx
 yy_inv = yy - vy

 unwarped_img = one_way_operation(warped_img, xx_inv, yy_inv)
```

Expected result:

```
  assert(img == unwarped_img)
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this goal? I am grateful for any hint.

Comment: Can you post the code for generating deformed mesh? I maybe able to help you then.