# Is there a simple way to map a texture to a different "UV" system in python?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, dlib

I really don't know if "UV's" is the right word as i'm from the world of Unity and am trying to write some stuff in python. What i'm trying to do is to take a picture of a human (from webcam) take the placement of their landmarks/key features and alter a second image (of a different person) to make their key features in the same place whilst morphing / warping the parts of their skin that are within the face to fit the position of the first input image (webcam)'s landmarks. After i do that I need to put the face back on the non-webcam input. (i'm sorry for how much that made me sound like a serial killer, stretching and cutting faces) I know that probably didn't make any sense but I want it to look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1b5aiTrGzY).

I have the face landmark and cutting done with `DLIB` and `OpenCV` but i need a way to find a way to take these "cut" face chunks and stretch them "dynamically". What I mean by dynamically is that you don't just put a mask on by linearly re-sizing it on 1 or 2 axises. You can select a point of the mask and change that, I wanna do that but my mask is my cut chunk and the point is a section of that chunk that needs to change for the chunk to comply with the position of the generated landmarks. I know this is a very hard topic to think about and if you guys need any clarification just ask. My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(gray)
    for face in faces:
        x1 = face.left()
        y1 = face.top()
        x2 = face.right()
        y2 = face.bottom()
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)



        for n in range(0, 68):
            x = landmarks.part(n).x
            y = landmarks.part(n).y
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 4, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

EDIT: No i'm not a serial killer

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907633/how-to-warp-an-image-using-deformed-mesh)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deform source image like a rubber sheet using 2 sets of keypoints, you need to use [thin plate spline (TPS)](https://github.com/cheind/py-thin-plate-spline), or, better, piecewice affine transformation like [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_piecewise_affine.html). The last one is more similar to texture rasterization methods (triangle to triangle texture transform).